# Enabling Intel Virtualization technology on a windows VM

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-fusion

I am on a mac using a windows 10 VM, vmware fusion, and I need to enable the Virtual Technology option from the window BIOS setting to properly use a VMware player.

I have tried hitting F10 and F12 while the VM is booting but I have not seen the option I need.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you really trying to run VMware Player *inside* VMware Fusion?  I'm not sure whether VMware supports nested virtualization ... why not run VMware Player in MacOS instead?

Comment: Yes, had issues doing so.  just installed the player on a PC.  No issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just ran VMware player on a PC.  No issues